# Bash concatenate wierd output?

Tags: regex, bash, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate an IP string, with the remainder of a RegExp, for a later command. Here is the code:

```
    ip=$(grep -oP 'server-ip=\K(.*)' server.properties)
    echo "Server IP: ${ip}"
    ip=${ip//\./\\\.}
    exp=':19132\s+0\.0\.0\.0:.*\s+\K([0-9]+)'
    regexp="${ip}$exp"
    echo "netstat -tulpn | grep -oP '${regexp}'"
    #pid=$(netstat -tulpn | grep -oP '${regexp}')
```

The value of $ip is a valid IP string. and it later then has the .'s escaped by \ (e.g. 127.0.0.1)

I am then trying to concatenate that $ip value, with the $exp. for an expected output of

```
    127\.0\.0\.1:19132\s+0\.0\.0\.0:.*\s+\K([0-9]+)
```

However, instead i am getting something along the lines of

```
    :19132\s+0\.0\.0\.0:.*\s+\K([0-9]+)\.0\.1
```

I'm fairly new to Bash, so i'm assuming this is something real easy, but any help?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't be needed, the value returned from that is a fine IP string e.g. 127.0.0.1

Comment: is it? really? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  then why don't you substitute it in your posted code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2bRbFnvR

Comment: @DanSpiteri Include it _in your post_. On this site we like our questions to be completely self-contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, but setting the ip explicitly in a test script with your code gets the expected output.  If modifying that on your box works, then I'd suspect the problem is with your grep to get the IP.

```
~$ cat test2.sh
    ip=127.0.0.1
    echo "Server IP: ${ip}"
    ip=${ip//\./\\\.}
    exp=':19132\s+0\.0\.0\.0:.*\s+\K([0-9]+)'
    regexp="${ip}$exp"
    echo "netstat -tulpn | grep -oP '${regexp}'"

~$ ./test2.sh
    Server IP: 127.0.0.1
    netstat -tulpn | grep -oP '127\.0\.0\.1:19132\s+0\.0\.0\.0:.*\s+\K([0-9]+)'
```

In fact, creating a server.properties like below:

```
~$ cat server.properties
   server-ip=127.0.0.1
```

Then running your script as is, seems to work.  The problem seems to lie somewhere in getting that value:

```
~$ cat ./test2.sh
    ip=$(grep -oP 'server-ip=\K(.*)' server.properties)
    echo "Server IP: ${ip}"
    ip=${ip//\./\\\.}
    exp=':19132\s+0\.0\.0\.0:.*\s+\K([0-9]+)'
    regexp="${ip}$exp"
    echo "netstat -tulpn | grep -oP '${regexp}'"
    #pid=$(netstat -tulpn | grep -oP '${regexp}')

~$ ./test2.sh
    Server IP: 127.0.0.1
    netstat -tulpn | grep -oP '127\.0\.0\.1:19132\s+0\.0\.0\.0:.*\s+\K([0-9]+)'
```

Comment: Aha! It was whitespace in the file, I changed the first line to ```ip=$(grep -oP 'server-ip=\K(.*)' server.properties | tr -d '[[:space:]]')``` and it works now! Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  Do heed the commenter's advice about forming a question, and don't forget in instances like this to isolate the different pieces that could fail.  You were very close to solving this on your own, when you're not getting the expected output from chained commands, always check them one by one.